# How to change background of TextView From EditText Text Change?

Tags: android, colors, background, android-edittext, textview

I am using Fragment class in which I want to change the color of Text View When text is changed on my edit Text. What are the possible ways to change the background color of TextView When Text is Changed in EditText . My code looks like this :

```
public class Fragment_AboutUs extends android.app.Fragment {
    TextView about_btn_call_customer;
    TextView about_btn_Submit;
    EditText about_feedback;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_fragment_about_us, container, false);
        //reference section
        about_btn_call_customer= (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.about_btn_call_customer);
        about_btn_Submit=(TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.about_btn_Submit);
        about_feedback=(EditText)rootView.findViewById(R.id.about_feedback);
        return rootView;
    }
}
```

Any kind of help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution is a little modification of @GuiihE codes.
Try this solution,it would work out as per your requirements:

```
TextWatcher textWatcher = new TextWatcher() {
@Override
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {}

@Override
public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {}

@Override
public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
    about_btn_Submit.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#9CCC65"));
}
```

};

editText.addTextChangedListener(textWatcher);

Answer (score 1):

Use a TextWatcher like this:

```
TextWatcher textWatcher = new TextWatcher() {
    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {}

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {}

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        textView.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#..."));
    }
};

editText.addTextChangedListener(textWatcher);
```

**Note:** You can also use  `textView.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.mycolor))`

Answer (score 0):

Add `TextChangedListener` to your `EditText` as follows:

```
about_feedback.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher(){
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        // do what ever you want to TextView
    }
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after){}
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count){}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `TextWatcher`

for eg:

```
EditText about_feedback= (EditText)findViewById(R.id.medittext);
about_feedback.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

        doSomething();



    } 

});
```

and you can use

```
about_btn_Submit.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"));
```

to change the color of the `TextView`

So,

in your code, do this in `onTextChanged()`, ie

```
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
     about_btn_Submit.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Guys for the answer @GuiLhe i Followed your answer,I wanted to change the background color of TextView so I wrote

`about_btn_Submit.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#9CCC65"));`

instead of

`textView.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#9CCC65"));`

Thank you again